# How can a Github workflow from one repo access to another repo's code within the same organization?

Tags: github-actions

Repos A and B are private repos within an organization. However every repo within the organization has the access restricted and only granted by a manual approval. The Github workflow is defined in repo A and wants to access repo B. But owners from B don't want to allow workflows from any repo within the organization, just the one defined in repo B, and if possible just an particular one. Is that possible, and if so how?

Notes:

1. [This](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/permissions?apiVersion=2022-11-28#set-the-level-of-access-for-workflows-outside-of-the-repository) is the closest I found, but it allows any workflow within
   the organization.
2. The background goal is to run the workflow in A
   that executes a program that needs code from repo B, C, D, E, etc.

Comment: A workaround could be to create a "service user account" in the organization, and generate a PAT for this service user account that could have access to both repository, using this PAT to clone the repo B from the repo A workflow.